# spree 3.0 bootstrap customization how to

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, spree

I've installed a Spree 3-0-Stable test site and I would like add bootswatch theme and change the padding of a few bootstrap items.

I'm struggling to understand where I do this.

One example is that I would like to modify the .panel-footer padding so and items price is shown in a smaller box.

I think that overrides should go in app/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend.

when I add the following

```
    .panel-footer {
      /* padding: 10px 15px; */
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
      border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    }
@import "bootstrap";
```

to

> app/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend/frontend_bootstrap.css.scss

the padding of the price box does not change , but the equal spacing of the items in the grid is lost.

I am going down the correct path to customize  the store like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no you should never customize in such a way,
Since when spree gets Updated all your components will be overriden by which u will lose all the updations Made.
So Better Start Using Deface Overrides Given in the spree guides.
First it'll be looking difficult
but once go through this video so that u can use the deface overrides concept easily.

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pirTIAy1NVM](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pirTIAy1NVM)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was more after info on where I put overrides to the CSS, i.e changing box types ,  colours , fonts in the bootstrap theme etc.